# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I add component to my panel, when I compile program it is working fine but when I run maven tests, it not pass and return information :

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.900s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 19 19:24:43 CEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/382M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 (default) 
    on project stockbox-bta: command execution failed: /Users/Arek/Projects/stockbox/bta/src/com/goodsoft/stockbox/bta/view/base/BtActionAutoClickItemView.form: 
    Cannot find nested form file com/goodsoft/stockbox/acs/view/panel/StopPanel.form
```

I am using `GUI Creator` in `IDEA Intellij`

Can somebody tell me what it means ? Why test can not find this `StopPanel.form`?

It is possible that I put on my view this `StopPanel.form` as a component, NOT in `JPanel` container ?

It could be problem with type of initialization ? Now it is basic initialization, maybe choose `Custom create` and manually create object of my form could help...

If You want see more code, please write which part of code You want to see.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Are you implementing any lambda expressions?

Comment: I'm using it too and I had the same problem. I'm using JAVA 8 and lambdas. Is there any problem with this?